# How to make the different color depending on today's date?

Tags: php, date

How can I change the different color of date if the date in the database is greater than today's date. In Picture, U can see the date under 002 is greater than today's date so the color must be green. If less tha toda's date, it has to be red. How can I do auto detect the date?

```
$type = $equipArray[$x];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM map_db_oee.`tbl_actual_correlation` WHERE `waferid` LIKE 'NSX1234%' AND prober=' '".$type."' ORDER BY dt_cor DESC LIMIT 1'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $date = "<br><font size=\"2px\" color=\"red\">".$row["dt_corr"]." </font>";
}
else {
  $date = "";
}
```

[image: Date must be green and auto detected.]

[image: This is example of code]

Comment: Please don't post code as comments, copy and paste the code within the post itself. Also, make sure to post a [mre].

Comment: i added the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $class = strtotime($row['dt_cor']) < time()  ? 'past' : 'up-coming'; ?>

<style>
    .date-el{font-size: 14px;display: inline-block;color: #000;}
    .date-el.past{color: #ccc;}
    .date-el.up-coming{color: #f00;}
</style>

<span class="date-el <?= $class; ?>"><?= $row['dt_cor']; ?></span>
```

adding style / class can solve your problem

add the css inside `<head>` tag, or it will be better if you maintain it inside your css file. [check css tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp)

Comment: Where should i put that style?

Comment: Where should i add the span class?

Comment: you can keep the date inside the span-element. But add the css classes ( as mentioned there ). <span class="...">date here</span> . The css/class is used to change the style of the html output.